# Making docker container a build executor for jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a ec2 instance running as my jenkins master. I would like to run a container in that instance that will be used as another build executor so I can tun a few builds simultaneously.

Im having pronblems connecting these.

In the docker hub jenkins docs it says under the relevant section:

> You can run builds on the master out of the box.
>
> But if you want to attach build slave servers through JNLP (Java Web
>   Start): make sure you map the port: -p 50000:50000 - which will be
>   used when you connect a slave agent.
>
> If you are only using SSH slaves, then you do NOT need to put that
>   port mapping.

but when I try to add a node in the jenkins config, it asks remote root directory (probably should be /var/jenkins ? ) and a launch method.

I don't quite understand what I should give it as its launch method to make this work and I don't understand where the port number comes into play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Jenkins Docker plugin (link below) and follow the instructions listed [here](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/)

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

I followed those instructions and was able to setup dynamic slaves in Jenkins which are dynamically provisioned.

Comment: if I want to run this on my master, whats the difference between this and adding more executors to my master?

Comment: Difference will be that builds will run within the container’s remote root directory as opposed to builds running within $JENKINS_HOME directory which is a security risk as anyone can access & modify files within this dir. Ideally you should never run your builds on master - it is not a best practice!